# Initializing an empty Stack

Tags: c++, class, null, initialization, stack

I'm trying to initialize an empty stack of size 3, but my program is not letting me put NULL into even 1 of the elements. I'm not sure what the problem is. The program just stops working when it attempts to initialize one of elements.

```
Stack300::Stack300 ()
{

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    stackArray[i] = '\0';
    //stackArray[i] = i;
}

top = 0;

return;
}
```

My .h file.

```
#ifndef CONGERA2_H
#define CONGERA2_H

typedef float Element300;

class Stack300
{
public:
    Stack300 ();
    Stack300 (const int);
    Stack300 (Stack300 &old);
    ~Stack300();
    void push300(const Element300);
    Element300 pop300();
    void viewTB300();
    void viewBT300();

private:
    const int MAX_STACK = 80;
    Element300 * stackArray;
    int top;

};

#endif
```

And my main file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "congera2.h"
using namespace std;



int main()
{

Element300 temp1 = 1.1;

Element300 temp2 = 2.2;

Element300 temp3 = 3.3;

Stack300 myStack;

Stack300 myStack2 (myStack);

/* myStack.push300(temp1);

myStack.push300(temp2);

myStack.push300(temp3);*/

cout << "hello";


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to show more code, else this question is not answerable.

Comment: Where is `stackArray` defined and initialized, and is it in scope here?

Comment: You have to allocate stackArray with a fixed size. Here is an example. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Comment: So I changed my constructor to have that instead. stackArray[3] = {'\0', '\0', \0'}; but now I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, you are never allocating any memory to the 'stackArray' member. The following line would accomplish initializing a dynamic array of 3 floating point integers.

```
stackArray = new float[3];
```

You will then want to make sure this memory is deallocated in the destructor as well.

Edited to add some useful resources; these pages do a good job explaining the concept behind pointers and dynamic memory allocation:
[Pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers),
[Dynamic Memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I apologize but it wouldn't let me comment due to lack of reputation.

Comment: The thing is, this is the answer to the OP's immediate problem. @Paul I'd expand this and turn it into a full-bodied answer. For one thing, it's pretty obvious that `stackArray = new Element300[MAX_STACK ];` is the OP's goal. Why OP is nulling three elements of it, smurfed if I know. Why they are writing `char`s into `float`s, again, smurfed if I know. Serious X-Y action going on here, but the answer to "Why is this crashing?" is unallocated memory.